# Copy and paste to another sheet two conditions two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to extract all row meeting the criteria in column G and z then copy to another sheet. Criteria in Column G is "Female" and Criteria in Z is >18. To be particular, I am looking to get all the females who are above 18 then copy the result to a new sheet.
Here the the two macro to that I need to combine
Thanks in advance

```
Sub CopyFemale()

    Dim c As range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet

    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    j = 1
    For Each c In Source.range("G1:G1000")
        If c = "Female" Then
           Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
           j = j + 1
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

```
    Sub CopyGreater()
    
        Dim c As range
        Dim j As Integer
        Dim Source As Worksheet
        Dim Target As Worksheet
    
        Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
        j = 1
        For Each c In Source.range("Z1:Z1000")
            If c >= 0 Then
               Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
               j = j + 1
            End If
        Next c
    End Sub
```

Comment: Try using `Range.AutoFilter` or `Range.AdvancedFilter`.

Comment: I don't know how to do that can you help me with the code

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a second test for Z>18 on the line where you test for "Female"

```vb
Sub CopyFemaleOver18()

    Dim c As Range, age, rng As Range
    Dim j As Long 'use Long not Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet

    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    j = 1
    For Each c In Source.Range("G2:G1000").Cells
        If c.Value = "Female" Then
            age = c.EntireRow.Columns("Z").Value
            If IsNumeric(age) Then
                If age > 18 Then
                    c.EntireRow.Copy Target.Rows(j)
                    j = j + 1
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: I get error on this line  If c.Value = "Female" And c.EntireRow.Columns("Z").Value > 18 Then

Comment: What error do you get?  What type of data is in ColZ ?

Comment: Tim Williams Type mismatch. Colz has formula but i tried with values also and was not the same. Do you have another idea?

Comment: Do any of those formulas not return numbers?  Any errors in the cells in ColZ?

Comment: ...you cannot compare an error value to 18 for example.

Comment: All return numbers

Answer (score 0):

If you use AutoFilter, you could copy the entire block of data without the need to loop.  Please try the following code and let me know how you go.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyFemale()
Dim Source As Worksheet, Target As Worksheet, LastRow As Long
Set Source = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set Target = Sheets("Sheet2")

With Source.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    .AutoFilter 2, "Female"
    .AutoFilter 3, ">18"
    .Copy Target.Cells(1)          ' Use this line to include headers
    '.Offset(1).Copy Target.Cells(1) ' Use this line to exclude headers
    .AutoFilter
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Kevin999 for your efforts but i get autofilter method of range class failed error. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: OK, I've changed the method of referring to the range of interest.  Try the new code.

Comment: Which column does your data actually start in?

Comment: Thanks Again, But not working still . Would you write one where you have Columns A,B,C. with A have Names, B having Gender then C having age and try to extract all the females above 18 then copy to another sheet say sheet2?

Comment: OK Wendi - code changed based on your latest comment.  All 3 suggestions so far have worked on my PC - if this one doesn't work for you then I really can't explain it further.  Good luck!

Comment: Kevin9999 - Thank you loads for time taken to help me not sure why it is not working this side. Will keep looking. Thank you one more time.